# RabbitMq, client close TCP connection abruptly

Tags: java, client, rabbitmq

i'm writting a small program for crawling all the urls received from a RabbitMQ queue. I've tested with about 6000 urls and after a half of them have been processed, the client stop without an exception, all the connections to the rabbitmq server are lost. I've checked also the log and have some thing like

```
=WARNING REPORT==== 7-Apr-2016::10:40:50 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.32373.9> (192.168.55.1:55716 -> 192.168.55.100:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly
```

I'm using this connection factory setting:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("192.168.55.100");
        factory.setUsername(params.username);
        factory.setPassword(params.password);
        factory.setVirtualHost(params.virtualHost);
        factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
        factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(2);
```

Do you have some ideas about this? Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to configure RabbitMQ and you OS to handle more connections.

Read this: https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html

> Erlang VM I/O Thread Pool Erlang runtime uses a pool of threads for
>   performing I/O operations asynchronously. The size of the pool is
>   configured via the +A VM command line flag, e.g. +A 128. We highly
>   recommend overriding the flag using the
>   `RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS` environment variable:
>
> RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS="+A 128"

and also this: https://www.rabbitmq.com/production-checklist.html

> Open File Handles Limit Operating systems limit maximum number of
>   concurrently open file handles, which includes network sockets. Make
>   sure that you have limits set high enough to allow for expected number
>   of concurrent connections and queues.